# How I can divide each column by a number in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 6000 columns which are gene names. It has 6 different features A,B,C,D,E,F with unique position numbers. I want to divide columns with feature A by 87 and feature B by 54.

At the end I want to have the sum and average of each row in new columns.
How I can do this in R?

```
feature_A=87
feature_B=54
```

Input file

```
 feature pos gene_1 gene_2 gene_3 gene_n
       A   1      6      2     51      0
       A   2      4      5      8      2
       A   3      1     74      5      0
       B   1     11      2     41     89
       B   2      4      5      3      5
```

Output file

```
 feature pos gene_1 gene_2 gene_3 gene_n  sum_all  average_all
       A   1   6/87   2/87  51/87   0/87 sum_row1 average_row1
       A   2   4/87   5/87   8/87   2/87 sum_row2 average_row2
       A   3   1/87  74/87   5/87   0/87 sum_row3 average_row3
       B   1  11/54   2/54  41/54  89/54 sum_row4 average_row4
       B   2   4/54   5/54   3/54   5/54 sum_row5 average_row5
       B   3   4/54   0/54   5/54  21/54 sum_row6 average_row6
```

Comment: "It has 6 different features A,B,C,D,E,F"  ; you need only A and B to divide? what happens with C,D,E,F rows?

Comment: I want to this for all features, here I only posted a subset of data

Comment: Great! The answers given are great for that with few modifications

Answer (score 6):

This might be made easier by merging your divisors in to your main dataset:

```
feat_div <- data.frame(feature=c("A","B"), value=c(87,54))
#  feature value
#1       A    87
#2       B    54

cols <- grepl("^gene_", names(dat))

dat <- merge(dat, feat_div)

dat[cols]       <- lapply(dat[cols], `/`, dat$value)
dat$sum_all     <- rowSums(dat[cols])
dat$average_all <- rowMeans(dat[cols])

#  feature pos     gene_1     gene_2     gene_3     gene_n value   sum_all average_all
#1       A   1 0.06896552 0.02298851 0.58620690 0.00000000    87 0.6781609   0.1695402
#2       A   2 0.04597701 0.05747126 0.09195402 0.02298851    87 0.2183908   0.0545977
#3       A   3 0.01149425 0.85057471 0.05747126 0.00000000    87 0.9195402   0.2298851
#4       B   1 0.20370370 0.03703704 0.75925926 1.64814815    54 2.6481481   0.6620370
#5       B   2 0.07407407 0.09259259 0.05555556 0.09259259    54 0.3148148   0.0787037
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` can do what you want, if you use a lookup table or the like to index what number to divide by:

```
library(dplyr)

# make a lookup vector
feat_num <- c(A = 87, B = 54)

feat_num
##
##  A  B 
## 87 54 

# group by feature and pos so they don't get divided
df %>% group_by(feature, pos) %>%    
    # divide everything but grouping variables (.) by the number looked up from feat_num
    mutate_each(funs(. / feat_num[feature])) %>%    
    # ungroup so next mutate works nicely
    ungroup() %>%    
    # add row sum and mean columns, indexing out the first and second columns
    mutate(sum_all = rowSums(.[-1:-2]), 
           average_all = rowMeans(.[-1:-2]))
##
## Source: local data frame [5 x 8]
## 
##   feature   pos     gene_1     gene_2     gene_3     gene_n   sum_all average_all
##    (fctr) (int)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)     (dbl)       (dbl)
## 1       A     1 0.06896552 0.02298851 0.58620690 0.00000000 0.6781609   0.1695402
## 2       A     2 0.04597701 0.05747126 0.09195402 0.02298851 0.2183908   0.0545977
## 3       A     3 0.01149425 0.85057471 0.05747126 0.00000000 0.9195402   0.2298851
## 4       B     1 0.20370370 0.03703704 0.75925926 1.64814815 2.6481481   0.6620370
## 5       B     2 0.07407407 0.09259259 0.05555556 0.09259259 0.3148148   0.0787037
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to split the data into two data frames, compute your values, then recombine them.  Assume your original dataframe is `df`:

```
df_A <- df[df$feature == 'A', -1]
df_A <- apply(df_A, 2, function(x) x/87)
df_B <- df[df$feature == 'B', -1] 
df_B <- apply(df_B, 2, function(x) x/54)

df2 <- rbind(df_A, df_B)

df2$sum_all <- rowSums(df2)
df2$avg_all <- rowMeans(df2)

df2 <- cbind(df2, df$feature)
```

This should divide each column with 'A' as a feature by 87, divide each column with 'B' as a feature by 54, recombine the rows and find the sum and mean for each row.  Please let me know if there are any issues as I can't test it right now.

EDIT: looks like the other answers are better, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the `feature` vectors to a data.frame ('d2') by placing them in a `list`, `stack` it to `data.frame`, change the column names and `transform` the 'feature' column to remove the prefix `feature_`.  We `join` this dataset with the original dataset ('d1') after converting 'd1' to `data.table` (`setDT(d1)`) and changing the column types of 'gene' columns from `integer` to `numeric`.  We join `on` the 'feature' column, `by` `.EACHI`, loop through the columns specified in `.SDcols`, divide by the 'value', get the row wise sum (`Reduce(...`) and average ('x3'), and assign (`:=`) the output to the names specified.

```
library(data.table)
d2 <- transform(setNames(stack(mget(paste("feature", c("A", "B"), 
        sep="_")))[2:1], c("feature", "value")), 
          feature = sub(".*_", "", feature))
nm1 <- grep("^gene", names(d1), value = TRUE)
setDT(d1)[, (nm1):= lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = nm1]
d1[d2, c(nm1, "sum_all", "average_all") :={
           x1 <- lapply(.SD, `/`, value)
           x2 <- Reduce(`+`, x1)
           x3 <- x2/length(nm1)
           c(x1, list(x2, x3))} ,
           on = "feature", by = .EACHI,.SDcols = nm1][]
#    feature pos     gene_1     gene_2     gene_3     gene_n   sum_all average_all
#1:       A   1 0.06896552 0.02298851 0.58620690 0.00000000 0.6781609   0.1695402
#2:       A   2 0.04597701 0.05747126 0.09195402 0.02298851 0.2183908   0.0545977
#3:       A   3 0.01149425 0.85057471 0.05747126 0.00000000 0.9195402   0.2298851
#4:       B   1 0.20370370 0.03703704 0.75925926 1.64814815 2.6481481   0.6620370
#5:       B   2 0.07407407 0.09259259 0.05555556 0.09259259 0.3148148   0.0787037
```

#### data

```
d1 <- structure(list(feature = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), pos = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), gene_1 = c(6L, 4L, 1L, 11L, 4L), gene_2 = c(2L, 
5L, 74L, 2L, 5L), gene_3 = c(51L, 8L, 5L, 41L, 3L), gene_n = c(0L, 
2L, 0L, 89L, 5L)), .Names = c("feature", "pos", "gene_1", "gene_2", 
"gene_3", "gene_n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can divide each column by the mean, or if you want to divide it by a specific number replace `mean(x)` with that number, or with `std(x)`, `median(x)`.

```
data(mtcars);head(mtcars)
mtcars[] <- lapply(mtcars,function(x) x / mean(x))
```

as the same token, you can do this for a single column as follows

```
data(mtcars);head(mtcars)
mtcars$mpg <- lapply(mtcars$mpg ,function(x) x / mean(x))
```